# RTSP live streaming from IP Camera

Tags: java-me, nokia, rtsp, live-streaming, ip-camera

Is it possible to see the live stream of an IP camera using RTSP ?

Example URL: rtsp://public ip:554/1363e66e.mp4

The encoding is mp4 h.264 baseline profile at 320 x 240 resolution.

I followed the Wiki link [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_play_video_streaming_in_Java_ME).
But I get the error: Prefetch error -2

When I try to play using real player on the nokia e72, I get the error: 'General: System Error'.

Please let me know what I can do about this.

There are no video players on Ovi store that can play the stream either but I am able to play the stream on VLC on the desktop.

Comment: Which IP camera are you using?  What resolution is it streaming at?  Is there a username / password which is needed?  Any firewall between the phone and camera?

Comment: Resolution: 320 x 240. No password. No firewall.

Comment: Can you stream any other RTSP sources?  If not, itooks like there may be an issue with the E72 - http://discussions.europe.nokia.com/t5/Phone-Applications/E72-Live-TV-streaming-from-Orange-Romania-General-system-error/m-p/760738?device-view=desktop

Comment: I can stream from youtube, but that is not live stream right ? But I have the same issue on Nokia C6-01 also.

Comment: Try to make sure that both the container (MP4) as the codec, can be processed by the library classes of Java ME javax.microedition.media.

Answer (score 1):

You can stream it using ReaPlayer if you don't have VLC player in Ovi store. See the port address range supported by your IP camera. Try the range of 1024 - 2000. RTSP supports VLC, Quicktime and Real player. Using any of these objects you can stream it.

Answer (score 0):

So I think here is the case,

There are a few different mp4 containers. Standard one wont allow you to wrap a real time data into a mp4 container because mp4 needs to have a field/atom in its header called 
MDAT and it has information about the file and its size as well.(which is written after the file is completely encoded. )

So unless you wake that you can not stream live stuff in mp4 UNLESS it is fragmented mp4.

Media Foundation will allow you to do this when windows 8 is out( i got the intel from the msdn forum so I dont know how true it is).
I dont know what ffmpeg/Gstreamer is capable of. Again if this is a commercial product you are working on you might run into some licensing issues with ffmpeg.

Look at webrtc.

I am guessing best bet it to use webm or ogg/theora but I am not sure if theora can do what you want, This is something I am also working on.

Please share your findings

Thanks.